# Google Maps API v3 Polylines not drawing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, data-visualization

App works this way:
User enters a starting location and a distance.  User can choose to draw circles, or lines over the roads. Circles work fine.  Lines used to work.

When Lines, the code finds the lat/long of the starting location, then for the points N, S, E, W of the origin at the distance set by the user (say, 100km).  Starting with the N destination, the code calls google.maps.DirectionsService() to get directions from the origin to N.  This returns an array of lat/longs in the the route.overview_path.

NOTE: I COULD use the directionsRenderer() to draw the route, BUT, the distance drawn would be greater than the distance set by the user. Drawing the entire route from the origin to the point N might be 124km over the roads, and I just want to draw 100km.

Instead, I step through the route.overview_path[] array, checking the distance between that point and the point of origin, adding each point to a new array.  When the distance is greater than the dist set by the user, I stop, pop off the last element, then create a new Polyline based on this 2nd, smaller array.

I've spent the entire day in Chrome's developer mode walking through the javascript, setting breakpoints, watching locals, etc.  The array of points passed in google.maps.Polyline({}) is a good array of unique points.  I just cannot figure out why they aren't rendering.

Ultimately, the code used to draw 4 lines starting at the point of origin, one heading North, one heading East, South, West. etc....

The code is here:  http://whosquick.com/RunViz.html

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Solved it.

```
var objGeo = new LatLon(Geo.parseDMS(myroute.overview_path[0].Pa), Geo.parseDMS(myroute.overview_path[0].Qa));
```

I had inadvertently switched Pa with Qa.